How to solve the exploding gradient problem in VAE training?
I was trying to implement VAE on the CelebA dataset inspired by the Tensorflow implementation of MNIST. I have tried varying batch size but there seems to be no effect from that. The image formed is mostly grey all the time. Ideally, we want KL divergence and Reconstruction loss both to be close to zero but in my case, both are increasing exponentially.

Here is the Loss function definition block:
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
def log_normal_pdf(sample, mean, logvar, raxis=1):
  log2pi = tf.math.log(2. * np.pi)
  return tf.reduce_sum(
      -.5 * ((sample - mean) ** 2. * tf.exp(-logvar) + logvar + log2pi),
      axis=raxis)
  
def compute_loss(model, x):
  mean, logvar = model.encode(x)
  z = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
  x_logit = model.decode(z)
  cross_ent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=x_logit, labels=x)
  #logpx_z = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x - x_logit), axis=[1, 2, 3])
  logpx_z = -tf.reduce_sum(cross_ent, axis=[1, 2, 3])
  logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0., 0.)
  logqz_x = log_normal_pdf(z, mean, logvar)
  return -tf.reduce_mean(logpx_z + logpz - logqz_x), logpx_z, logqz_x-logpz

My latent dimension is 16 and batch size is 500. Also, my input is only 500 images.
I have already tried changing the size of input but there seems to be no impact from that. Here is the model definition:
class CVAE(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(CVAE, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(64, 64, 3)),
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                    filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                    filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                    filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                    filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                    filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                # No activation
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim + latent_dim),
            ]
        )

        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(latent_dim,)),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4*4*256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(4, 4, 256)),
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
                    filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same',
                    activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
                    filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same',
                    activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
                    filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same',
                    activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
                    filters=3, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'),
            ]
        )
    @tf.function
    def sample(self, eps=None):
        if eps is None:
            eps = tf.random.normal(shape=(100, self.latent_dim))
        return self.decode(eps, apply_sigmoid=True)

    def encode(self, x):
        mean, logvar = tf.split(self.encoder(x), num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
        return mean, logvar

    def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):
        eps = tf.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
        return eps * tf.exp(logvar * .5) + mean

    def decode(self, z, apply_sigmoid=False):
        logits = self.decoder(z)
        if apply_sigmoid:
            probs = tf.sigmoid(logits)
            return probs
        return logits


Here's is the link to the colab notebook

the ELBO should be positive, as it’s the sum of the reconstruction and the KL

@Alberto Ya I just reversed the sign. ELBO in my code is the sum of negative log-likelihood and KL Divergence.

please post the new loss
